# SQL 2008 SSAS processing successful but not finishing

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, olap-cube

Recently, we seem to have developed a problem within SSAS (SQL 2008 R2 SP1 CU5).

Whenever I manually process any of our cubes, the job will succeed and then go to the "Process succeeded.  Trace information is still being written......." notification.

However, this bit never finishes, so I never get the option to "Close" and I end up having to hit the "Stop" button.

The process seems to have worked, but I cannot figure out why this is happening.
I've googled, but can't find anything, and I'm hoping that someone on here can at least set me in the right direction.

As an example, the following screenshot is taken from a cube that processed in around 3 seconds, but I am still looking at this screen after 10 minutes.

[image: Processing_Issue]

Any ideas would be very welcome.

Thanks
craig

Answer (score 0):

Just read the text to the end. It explicitly states: `Process succeeded. Trace information is still being transferred. If you do not want to wait for all of the information to arrive press Stop.` Hitting the "Stop" button does not stop processing, as that has finished already. It will just stop transferring the status details back to your computer. And after you have hit the Stop button, the Close button will be enabled and you can close the dialog normally.

There seems to be a bug which Microsoft claims to be not reproducible, see http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/536543/

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly this was fixed in SP 1.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/as_emea/archive/2012/10/16/where-did-my-progress-report-events-go.aspx